# On Rolle's Theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, rolles-theorem

Assuming that the function $f$ is differentiable in $(0,1)$ and continuous on $[0,1]$. If $f(1) = 0$, show that there exists one $c \in (0,1)$, such that
$$f(c) = \frac{c f'(c)}{100}.$$

**My Attempt:**
I want to use Rolle's Theorem by defining $g(x) = xf(x)$.
See that $g(0) = 0 = g(1)$. So that there exists $c$ such that
$$g'(c) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow f(c) + cf'(c) = 0.$$
But I still don't get the answers.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it  $f(c) = -\frac{c f'(c)}{100}$? or $f(c) = \frac{c f'(c)}{100}$?

Comment: $f(c) = \frac{c f'(c)}{100}$. 
I am sure about it.

Comment: Then it is false as shown by cwlo2F

Comment: Ah, ok got it. Thankyou.

Comment: If you apply Rolle's Theorem to $x^{100}f(x)$ you get the same conclusion except for a minus sign. I think there is a typo in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think $f(x) = 1 - x$ gives a counterexample for your statement.

One has $f'(x) = -1$, and the solution of
$$ 1 - c = -\frac{c}{100} $$
is $c = \frac{100}{99}$, which is not in $(0, 1)$.

Comment: Wonderful!
Thanks in advance.